# Sans-serif Uppercase Greek no-longer showing in acmart

Tags: fonts, greek

I have a document (in the acmart class) that is supposed to write a sans-serif Gamma:

```
\documentclass{acmart}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\sbox0{$\mathsf{\Gamma}$}
{\tracingall\scrollmode\showbox0 }
\usebox{0}

\end{document}
```

and whose log is here: https://pastebin.com/M1aDaFDQ
I guess the interesting line is 949:

```
.\T1/LinuxBiolinumT-TLF/m/n/9 ^^@
```

In my old macbook, it shows fine, the log i get there is: https://pastebin.com/GS1imAYa
In my new macbook pro, however, it shows a back tick "  `  ". I know this issue also arises on other laptops running different OS, like Linux (don't know the specific distro though).

The problem occurs with other uppercase greek, such as \Pi, but not with \Sigma, nor with any lowercase greek.

I also tried adding `\tracinglostchars=3`, but nothing pops up.

Is there a way to reverse engineer what was going on in my old laptop (which i still have) in order to make the new one print the uppercase greek correctly?

Comment: I added an example, that should show: a log of `.\OT1/cmss/m/n/10 ^^@` where cmss shows it is using a sans serif font. Please show the full log you get

Comment: the version of pdftex, the operating system and system installed fonts will not affect things here, package versions and tex-installed fonts may, so add `\listfiles` to a test document and compare the package versions in the log file

Comment: This most often happens when a document directly or indirectly  inculded the command `\usepeackge][T1](fontenc}`. The T1 font encoding does not contain uppercase Greek.

Comment: If you add `\tracinglostchars=3`, do you get any error message about a missing symbol?

Comment: @egreg: thanks, i thought the problem was generic but indeed it shows up only on acmart (added for clarification). 
@DavidCarlisle: added the logs as requested
@Davislor: tried with and without the `[T1](fontenc)`, but i guess `acmart` does something funky.

Comment: @Squera Ah! Yes. That’s it. `acmart.cls` has the line `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}` and `\usepackage[tt=false, type1=true]{libertine}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

The problem, which I’m embarrassed to say I overlooked, is that the document class you loaded, `amsart`, loads the commands

```
\usepackage[tt=false, type1=true]{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
```

These change the text font encoding from the 7-bit OT1 from the 1980s, which contains capital Greek letters, to the 8-bit T1 encoding from the 1990s, which put accents in the same slots.

You can fix this by loading a sans-serif font with the encoding you want.  If you wanted an upright sans-serif font with support for both capital and lowercase Greek letters, your best option would be to switch to Unicode fonts with `fontspec`.  You can, however, load a matching `\mathsf` alphabet with capital Greek letters (such as Libertinus Sans) with the following:

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\tracinglostchars=3 % Make missing symbols an error!

\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbers

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OT1}{LibertinusSans-LF}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}{OT1}{LibertinusSans-LF}{bx}{n}

\begin{document}

\[ \mathop{\textsf{sin}} \mathsf{\Gamma} \quad \mathop{\textsf{Tr}} \boldsymbol{\mathsf{\Gamma}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Libertius Sans sample]

### Original Answer

I’m not able to duplicate your bug, but one possible kludgy workaround would be to manually set `\mathsf` to an alphabet that definitely covers Greek capital letters. (There are not very many good options in legacy 8-bit TeX if  you also need upright sans-serif lowercase Greek, but there are a huge number of them if you switch to `unicode-math`.)

For example, this might solve your immediate problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3 % Make missing symbols an error!

\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbers

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}{OT1}{cmss}{bx}{n}

\begin{document}

\[ \mathsf{\Gamma} \quad \boldsymbol{\mathsf{\Gamma}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern Sans Serif sample]

However, the important line here is not the `\DeclareMathAlphabet`.  It’s the `\tracinglostchars=3`.  If you’re getting this bug with that MWE, something funny is going on with your installation, and you want to diagnose what that is, not keep kludging your way around it.

Because of a piece of technical debt to the 1980s, the default behavior of TeX, when you request a symbol that the current font does not have, is to print a blank space and *silently* log an error message to the middle of the `.log` file.  You instead want it to stop and print the error message that tells you what is actually wrong.

I will take a guess, however, that some package you loaded directly or indirectly changed the encoding of `\mathsf` from `OT1`, in which slot `"00` is Γ, to `T1`, in which the same slot is a backtick.  However, there does not appear to be any line of your MWE that should be doing that.